# How can I insert elements in an alphabetically sorted list in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a linked list consisting of `Node`s which have a `char` item as a payload.
New nodes should be insered alphabetically.

When trying to retrieve the elements of the list, I receive a `Segmentation Fault`. That means I'm accessing an invalid address somehow.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
    struct node *next;
    char *item;
} Node;

static Node *list = NULL;

void insert(char *item) {
    Node *currentNode = list;
    while (strcmp(currentNode->item, item) < 0) {
        printf("next..\n");
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
    Node *new = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new->item = item;
    Node *tmp = currentNode->next;
    currentNode->next = new;
    new->next = tmp;
}

void retrieve() {
    Node *current = list;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        printf("%c", *(current->item));
        current = current->next;
    }   
    printf("\n");
}


int main() {

    // Initialize.
    list = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    char a = 'a';
    list->item = &a;
    retrieve();

    char b = 'b';
    char c = 'c';

    insert(&b);
    retrieve();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The algorithm is incorrect. Your insertion function search for the first element bigger or equal to the element to insert, and insert the element after it. It should insert in front of it. To do so you should keep track of the address of the previous element and insert after the previous element. This doesn't explain the segmentation fault.

Comment: There are quite a few errors in your code, but one major problem is that `strcmp` requires **nul-terminated** strings, and you're not giving it such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `currentNode` to be a reference pointer to the current node, so I think in `insert()` you need to replace:

```
Node *currentNode = list;
```

and:

```
currentNode = currentNode->next;
```

and:

```
currentNode->next = new;
```

with:

```
Node **currentNode = &list;
```

and:

```
currentNode = &(currentNode->next);
```

and:

```
*(currentNode->next) = new;
```

In `retrieve()` you don't need a reference pointer (as you're not changing data), just a regular pointer. So replace:

```
Node *current = list;
```

with:

```
Node current = list;
```

Your compiler probably warned you about assigning mismatching types.

Also you're mixing char* strings and references to single chars (which aren't strings as they won't have the NULL terminator).
For example:

```
char b = 'b';
insert(&b);
```

should be:

```
char* b = "b";
insert(b);
```

Comment: @AdrianMole That should have been `currentNode = &(currentNode->next);`, sorry about the typo.
And you're right: in `insert()` it should be a reference pointer like this: `Node **currentNode = &list;` (I have updated my answer above)

Answer (score 2):

You only partially define `list`. Where you have

```
list->item = &a;
```

you should also have

```
 list->next = NULL;
```

As Adrian Mole suggests, you should also be inputting null terminated strings. E.g. `"a"` rather than `'a'`.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `strcmp` implies that `item` is a null terminated sequence of characters. But in `main` you pass a pointer to a single character which is by the way a local variable allocated on the stack. This is not a null terminated string.

You should use the call `insert(strdup("abc"));` for instance. `strdup("abc")` will copy the string given as argument in a block allocated with `malloc`. The returned address is of a null terminated string and can be inserted as item value in new item nodes.

Another problem is in the insertion function. You don't check if the end of list is reached. `currentNode` may be null.

There is another problem with the insertion function. It will not insert the item at the correct position. The faulty code searches the first node with an item bigger or equal to the item to insert. It then insert the item after the node. The order may thus be invalid since the node item may be bigger than the item to insert. The correct insertion should insert before the found node.

Here is a fixed version of insert:

```
void insert(char *item) {
    Node **nodePtr = &list;
    while (*nodePtr != NULL && strcmp((*nodePtr)->item, item) < 0) {
        printf("next..\n");
        nodePtr = &(*nodePtr)->next;
    }
    Node *new = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new->item = item;
    new->next = *nodePtr;
    *nodePtr = new;
}
```

In this code `nodePtr` is a pointer to a pointer on a node. It is initialized as a pointer to list which holds a pointer to the first node or null if the list is empty. `nodePtr` is updated to move along the list until the end is reached or the pointed node has an item big or equal to the item to insert. We insert the new node in front of it.